# Angular 8 - subscribe to one service from two different components

Tags: angular, service, components, observable, subject

I have an angular service and two different unrelated components that use this service:

Service Code:

```
const url = 'ws://localhost:8080

@Injectable({
   provideIn: 'root',
})

export class MyService{

  public subject: Subject<Status>;

  constructor(wsService: WebSocketService){
    this.subject = <Subject<Status>>wsService.connect(url).map(
       (response: MessageEvent): Status => {
          let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
          return data;
        }
    );
  }

  getObs(){
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

  sendMsg(msg){
    this.subject.next(msg);
  }

}
```

Component 1:

```
@Component

.. some irrelevant code ..

constructor(private service: MyService){
  this.service.getObs().subscribe( data => 
    console.log('comp1');
  );

  console.log('comp1 - after subscribe');
}

.. some irrelevant code ..
```

Component 2:

```
@Component

.. some irrelevant code ..

constructor(private service: MyService){
  this.service.getObs().subscribe( data => 
    console.log('comp2');
  );

  console.log('comp2 - after subscribe');
}

.. some irrelevant code ..
```

I get the following output in the console:

**comp1**

**comp1 - after subscribe**

**comp2 - after subscribe**

the output I think I should get:

**comp1**

**comp1 - after subscribe**

**comp2**

**comp2 - after subscribe**

Can anyone explain what the problem is?

Note: I added my service to the Module providers and got the same result.

Thanks.

here's the code for webSocketService: https://github.com/elliotforbes/ng-chat/blob/master/src/app/common/services/websocket.service.ts

Comment: What data type does `wsService.connect(url)` return?

Comment: And is `WebSocketService` something you have created?

Comment: MyService doesn't have any obvious replay behaviour, does component 2 start subscribing *after* the message that triggers component 1's output?

Comment: here's the code for webSocketService:
https://github.com/elliotforbes/ng-chat/blob/master/src/app/common/services/websocket.service.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take control of your own subjects rather than piggybacking on `WebSocketService.connect` and assuming that you're going to get the desired behaviour.

From the link to the source code of `WebSocketService` that you posted, we see that it is a plain subject. The functionality you desire - emitting a value upon subscription (providing one exists) - is provided by `ReplaySubject`.

You should declare a local `ReplaySubject`, which is what your components will subscribe to. You would then subscribe to your `WebSocketService`. Any responses that come from the `WebSocketService` will be mapped to a status and then sent to your local subject.

```js
const url = 'ws://localhost:8080

@Injectable({
   provideIn: 'root',
})

export class MyService{

  // Declare local ReplaySubject that emits the last value upon subscription
  private subject: Subject<Status> = new ReplaySubject<Status>(1);

  constructor(wsService: WebSocketService) {
    // Subscribe to the web socket service.
    // Subscribing in constructors is fairly bad practice, 
    // although you can get away with it in singleton services
    wsService.connect(url).pipe(
      // map responses to statuses
      map((response: MessageEvent): Status => {
        let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        return data;
      })
    ).subscribe((status: Status) => {
      // send the status to all subscribers
      this.subject.next(status);
    });
  }

  getObs(): Observable<Status> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

  sendMsg(msg): void {
    this.subject.next(msg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use Behaviour Subject Instead of Normal Subject.

https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0

Comment: We don't know what kind of subject is being used - it's just being cast to a `Subject<Status>` - that doesn't mean that it is actually a normal `Subject`. We need more information about the code.

Comment: https://alligator.io/rxjs/subjects/

For details about subjects.
It's sure that it's not a behavior Subject.
You can use behavior Subject as below.
` private categories: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});`

Comment: I'm well aware of the different types of subject. OP clearly needs a `ReplaySubject`, as there is no initial state. But we don't know what `wsService.connect(url)` returns, so any answers would only be guesses